# ImageField's "Currently" and "Clear" Sometimes Doesn't Appear

Tags: django

Assume you have a model that has a required field of any type and also an optional ImageField. Let's say you used Django's built-in admin interface to insert a row into this database table and when you did so, you filled out both fields. Now let's say you go to edit the row that you just created. The ImageField will look like this:

Currently: [url] | [checkbox] Clear
Change: [file widget]

If you upload a non-image (a PDF, for example), it will say "Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image." only now the "Currently: [url] | [checkbox] Clear" portion won't be there anymore. This can be misleading to users (causing them to think the original image is now gone).

Another issue is let's say you were editing the row and you blanked out the required field and also replaced the image with another one. It will, of course, complain about the required field not being filled out. But, again, the "Currently: [url] | [checkbox] Clear" portion of the image field won't be there anymore. Again, this can mislead the user.

Is this a bug or is this the intended behavior? Either way, how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since two weeks have passed and nobody has answered this, I thought it must be a question more for the Django developers. [I asked them](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/django-developers/3lpFZ380dzQ/discussion) and Carl Meyer said he'd call it a bug. He asked me to file a bug report for it, so I did:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19215